# Genymotion in android studio but could not get path in windows 10

Tags: android, genymotion

I am having a problem in windows 10 i have installed genymotion in android studio but i could not find the path for it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For windows, the default path is `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`

On a Mac, you will find it here: `/Applications/Genymotion.app`